# Topological singularity

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

$t = \{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$, is not a topology for set, $\{x, y\}$, because $\{x\}\cup\{x, y\} = \{x, x, y\}$, is not an element of $t$, but wouldn't this be the case for any finite open set?

Comment: Do you mean $\tau=\{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{x,y\}\}?$ In such a case it is a topology on $X=\{x,y\}.$ Note that $\{x\}\cup \{x,y\}=\{x,y\}.$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think we're not supposed to use multisets here?

Comment: $\{x,x,y\}=\{x,y\}$. A set is determined by its elements.

Answer (score 0):

When a set is denoted or described using brace brackets it means that its members are all those and only those things that meet the conditions or formula within the brackets, or, all and only those things that are equal to something appearing on a list within the brackets. So $V=\{x,x,y\}$ means that any $z\in V$ iff $(z=x$ or $z=x$ or $z=y$). So $\{x,x,y\}=\{x,y\}.$